# Migrate existing third-party Django model to new customized model

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-filer

I'm using [django-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) for file handling. It has abstract model `BaseImage` and also there is default model for images called `Image` which inherits from `BaseImage` and not abstract.

Also, this package allows to specify custom model for images: it hooks import of `Image` model, checks `FILER_IMAGE_MODEL` setting and return custom model if it's specified instead of `Image`.
[here is the code](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer/blob/bb0bfa4bd9dccd18c05f01f4da2ef9e7ed1a8858/filer/models/imagemodels.py#L24)

So, customizing is easy -- I inherited my model `CustomImage` from `BaseImage` and specified necessary setting -- all works fine. But here comes trouble: how to properly migrate existing data from old models to new ones?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) the details of which will depend on your models.